# How to find the max value by country and year in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have multiple rows of data for the same year of the same country. I want to make it such that I only have 1 row of data for a particular year in a country. I want my indicator variable to be the maximum possible value across all rows of the same year in the same country For example, my data currently looks like:

| country | Year | Trial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1980 | 1 |
| Afghanistan | 1980 | 0 |
| Afghanistan | 1981 | 0 |
| Afghanistan | 1981 | 0 |
| Afghanistan | 1982 | 1 |
| Afghanistan | 1982 | 1 |

and I want to make it such that it looks like:

| country | Year | presenceofTrial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1980 | 1 |
| Afghanistan | 1981 | 0 |
| Afghanistan | 1982 | 1 |

For 1980, since my first row was 1 and my second row was 0, my final and only row for 1980 should take the maximum value which is 1, etc.

I'm currently using the code:

```
dataset %>% group_by(country, Year) %>% 
  summarise(
    presenceofTrial = max(dataset$Trial))
```

However, that just returns 1 for every row regardless of whether 1 is actually in the original table. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison. You also shouldn't use `dataset$` inside your `dplyr` functions, since it's taking the maximum of that whole vector, not the column by group

Comment: Yes, I want to assign the max value of Trial to the variable presenceofTrial

Comment: Got it, it works now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways (the second one is more in line with your code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    country = rep("Afghanistan", 6),
    Year = rep(1980:1982, each = 2),
    Trial = c(1,0,0,0,1,1)
)

first_method <- df %>%
    group_by(Year, country) %>%
    filter(Trial == max(Trial)) %>%
    slice(1)

second_method <- df %>%
    group_by(country,Year) %>%
    summarize(
        PresenceofTrial = max(Trial)
    )
```